# TestNG method execution default priority sequence

Tags: testng

I was exploring TestNG annotations. I came across below scenario, suppose I have 3 test and I have specified priority to 2 tests, one is default test without priority annotation

```
@Test(groups={"smoke","sanity"},priority=1)
public void TestCase2(){
    System.out.println("TestCase2");
}

@Test(priority=0)
public void TestCase3(){
    System.out.println("TestCase3");
}

@Test()
public void TestCase1(){
    System.out.println("TestCase1");
}
```

Output : TestCase1
TestCase3
TestCase2

Even if I change a sequence of  TestCase3 & TestCase1, output is same.

I know that

> If you don't mention the priority, it will take all the test cases as "priority=0" and execute.

**Question** is why TestCase1 is getting executed before TestCase3 ?

this is because 1 come before 3 so till testcase averything is same but diffrence id numeric value . and by default priority is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Test(priority=0)
public void TestWithZeroPriority(){}

@Test
public void TestWithDefaultPriority(){}
```

TestNG considers both Testcases having same priority signature. So both test case TestNG internally interprets as below

```
@Test(priority=0)
public void TestWithZeroPriority(){}

@Test(priority=0)
public void TestWithDefaultPriority(){}
```

Now TestNG executes tests as per alphabetical order. So `TestWithDefaultPriority()` will be executed first and then `TestWithZeroPriority()` will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

TestNG doesn't specify an order by default if you don't configure it. And it may change between versions.

In your example, the observed result is correct but the expected one could be too.

Comment: Yeah ! That's what ! Even if i assign default priority 0 to TestCase1 and remove priority 0 from TestCase3, output remains same. No conclusion.

Comment: As I remember, priority is 0 by default. Setting it with 0 or nothing will have the same result

Answer (score 1):

Using testng one can assign priority about in what order script execute different test cases. If one doesn't assign priority in the script and just mention only @Test to all test cases then there is a chance that script just randomly execute all different test and that may cause script failure. For example, you have login test then you have user personal information from fill up validation. So in this case if you haven't assign priority to login test and user personal information fill up test then script may execute user personal information fill up test first and then login test, in this case script fail as on the login screen script is executing user personal information fill up test.

Instead, if you assign priority @Test(priority = 0) to login test then @Test(priority = 1) to user personal information fill up test then script must execute priority=0 first and priority=1 later.

And testNG annotation @Test(priority=0), @Test(priority = 1) and so on... is very important when you want to generate test execution report.

Comment: Thanks for helpful explanation :). But I was wondering if you mention priority=0 and no priority property which Test should execute first ? I have come to the conclusion that, does not matter you provide priority property or priority=0, both will be having the same signature for TestNG.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the attached screenshot it looks like `no priority` is executed first then the priority `Zero`, irrespective of the order of method in the test.

[image]